# MOSFET Small signal analaysis question

Tags: circuit-analysis, analog

I must have spent 20 hours on this question and still i have not prevailed with an answer.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9mKRs.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnZlNJ.png)</sup>

Every time i end up stuck with to many unknowns.
So circuit 1 is the general circuit, circuit 2 is DC model, Circuit 3 is small signal model

So from the beginning.

1. Assume saturation mode.
2. Because drain current is given and gm, VGS(DC) can be accordingly be solved. Gm=1mS VGS(DC)=1.5 V
3. Issue in DC analysis. when drawing DC model you short all small signal voltage sources. Now at Vin in the second schematic. does that get short circuited because somewhere behind that point there must most definitely be an small signal source. If it it short circuited the VGS DC value of 1.5 V is not possible.therefor presumably it must be left as an open circuit? to have a 1.5 VGS value? This delema would not be an issue if there was a cap in the diagram and then the Vin source. unfortunately not the case.
4. Vout in dc analysis left as an open circuit
5. Move to small signal analysis
6. See working out in attatched image. KVL from Vin->R1-> Ground and KVL            vin->R2->R3->ground applied. Not that Rin = Vin/Iin. Apply 1 V test voltage to Vin. coresponding I Test= 2x10^-6 A.
7. Results in expression for R2 in terms of a constant and I2 and an expression for R1 in terms of I1
8. From here? I'm not sure

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your schematic is not showing a mosfet but an npn bjt.

Comment: Far out. Sorry. Yea should be an NMOs

Comment: Why did you calculate the small signal behavior? Is there something in the question that relates to the AC behavior?

Comment: You can relate R1 and R2 to Rin (which is given), in small signal mode. Thats the logic.

Comment: Well I can tell that neither the gate or output should be biased to 0V for the DC solution. If the gate was tied to ground, you could never have a bias current through the NMOS (\$V_{GS} = 0\$). Tying the output to ground would not make sense either as there is a DC current flowing through the NMOS, that continues through R3.

Comment: Thanks, yea its contradictory to the VG obtained at the start for the gate to be tied to ground. Its just a little confusing because in the DC analysis of the circuit you would short circuit all AC sources. and if the MOSFET is amplfilieng a small signal from Vin there most definitely must be  Voltage source of some sort to the left of the Vin terminal, just not shown.

Comment: Maybe the exercise assumes a current input, in which case you have to open-circuit it.

Comment: Do you understand how the FET is bootstrapping R2?

Comment: Not particularly, I understand that the voltage drop across R2 is controlling the current through the fet? But also the current from the FET through R3 also effects the voltage drop across R2. So its sort of funny because if Vi is initialy 0 and increased to some set point then as current increases through R3 Due to the current through R2 and the FET current the voltage drop across R2 gets regualted in some way due to this relationship

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In DC, we can find some useful equations by using the information about the transistor.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmCWda.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

$$V_{GS} = 1.5V = I_{R2}\cdot R_2 \Rightarrow I_{R2} = \frac{1.5V}{R_2}$$

The current \$I_{R2}\$ flows through \$R_3\$, along with the transistor's \$I_{DS}\$, giving another linear equation:

$$V_{OUT} = R_3\cdot (I_{R2} + I_{DS}) = 2k\Omega \cdot (I_{R2} + 0.5mA)$$

Finally, we also can bring \$R_2\$ into the equations by using that the voltages across all resistors need to add up to \$V_{DD}\$. Remember that the current through \$R_1\$ is the same as \$I_{R2}\$.

$$V_{OUT} = V_{DD} - 1.5V - R_1I_{R2} = 1.5V - R_1I_{R2}$$

As we are interested in \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$, we can eliminate \$I_{R2}\$ and \$V_{OUT}\$.

$$\begin{align}
1.5V - R_1I_{R2} &= 2k\Omega\cdot (I_{R2} + 0.5mA) \\
\Rightarrow 1.5V - \frac{R_1}{R_2}1.5V &= 2k\Omega\cdot \left( \frac{1}{R_2}1.5V + 0.5mA \right) \\
\Rightarrow R_2 - 3R_1 &= 6k\Omega
\end{align}$$

In small signal analysis, assuming you have an input current of \$i_{in}\$, you can find the input impedance using the following KCL equations:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fffrZo.png)</sup>

$$
\begin{align}
\left( \frac{1}{R_1} + \frac{1}{R_2} \right)v_{in}& - \frac{1}{R_2}v_{out} &=& i_{in} \\
-\left( \frac{1}{R_2} + g_m \right) v_{in}& + \left(\frac{1}{R_2} + \frac{1}{R_3} + g_m \right)v_{out} &=& 0
\end{align}
$$

(We don't need the KCL law for the output because it is "hidden" by the voltage-controlled current source, and we are only interested in \$v_{in}\$).

The input impedance can be found from these equations (while substituting \$R_3 = 2k\Omega\$ and \$g_m = 1/1k\Omega\$):

$$
\begin{align}
Z_{in} &= \frac{v_{in}}{i_{in}} \\
   &= \frac{R_1(R_2R_3g_m+R_3+R_2)}{R_2R_3g_m+R_3+R_2+R_1} \\
   &= \frac{R_1(2k\Omega+3R_2)}{2k\Omega+3R_2+R_1}
\end{align}
$$

Leading to the final equation (\$Z_{in} = 500k\Omega\$)

$$\begin{align}
(2k\Omega+3R_2+R_1)\cdot 500k\Omega &= R_1(2k\Omega+3R_2) \\
\Rightarrow 3\frac{R_1}{1k\Omega}\frac{R_2}{1k\Omega} &= 1k\Omega + 1.5R_2 + 0.498R_1
\end{align}$$

We now have 2 equations for solving 2 unknowns, which leads to the following quadratic equation (eliminating \$R_1\$):

$$\frac{R_2^2}{1k\Omega} - 1672R_2 - 4k\Omega = 0$$

Taking the positive solution will finally result into

$$\begin{align}
R_2 &= (10\sqrt{6989}+836)\ k\Omega \approx 1672\ k\Omega \\
R_1 &= \frac{R_2 - 6k\Omega}{3} \approx 555\ k\Omega
\end{align}$$